# Linked List Queue in C: Exception thrown: read access violation. temp was 0x740069

Tags: c, linked-list, queue, memory-access

I was making simple Linked list Queue program using C and i get this exception from my print function.

**Exception thrown: read access violation. temp was 0x740069.**

I'm still a beginner when it comes to C language so I don't getting use to managing memory and using pointers yet. So I'm not sure if the cause comes from my push function or my print function.

So i would like to ask what is the cause of this exception and how to fix it.

My code are as follow

```
struct node_struct {
    char *data;
    struct node_struct *next;
};

typedef struct node_struct Node;

struct queue_struct {
    Node *head, *tail;
};

typedef struct queue_struct Queue;

void push(Queue *q, char *word) 
{
    // IMPLEMENT
    Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    temp->data = word;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (q->head == NULL )
    {
        q->head= temp;
    }
    else
    {
        q->tail->next = temp;
    }
    q->tail = temp;
    q->tail->next = q->head;
}

char *pop(Queue *q) 
{
    // IMPLEMENT
    Node* temp = q->head;
    char n = q->head->data;
    q->head = q->head->next;
    free(temp);
    return(n);
}

void print(Queue *q) 
{
    // IMPLEMENT
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        printf("No Items\n");
    }
    else
    {
        //Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        Node* temp = q->head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("%c\n", temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

void print(Queue *q) 
{
    // IMPLEMENT
    if (q == NULL || isEmpty(q))
    {
        printf("No Items\n");
    }
    else
    {
        //Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        Node* temp = q->head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("%c\n", temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}


int isEmpty(Queue *q) 
{
    // IMPLEMENT
    if (q->head == NULL)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void delete(Queue *q) 
{
    // IMPLEMENT
    Node* temp;
    while (q->head != NULL)
    {
        temp = q->head;
        q->head = q->head->next;
        delete(temp);
    }
    q->tail = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Queue *q = NULL;

    // print the queue
    print(q);

    // push items
    push(&q, "a");
    push(&q, "b");
    push(&q, "c");
    print(q);
}
```

And the output is in image below

[Current output of my Queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54s5M.png)

Comment: Well I have written days ago a small library for linked lists, the purpose is to create a list that can be manipulated like arrays in JavaScript, so you can push, remove, clear, unshift, replace, pop... actually more than 40 functions, take a look on it https://github.com/SaymoinSam/STF_Lists maybe you will have some ideas. or maybe if you need such behaviour you can use it, or maybe follow it and make your own... and it's safe to use I have tested almost all cases and no memory leaks, no unauthorized access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in my case I use a field to store the size of the list, but it can be done without it, here is my implementation for a queue, I have added some comments for clarity, maybe you will find it useful. and i have added just few functions, you can add more if you like, it's just for giving you a startup :)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// make an alias for better readability
typedef char * String;

typedef struct node_struct {
  String data;
  struct node_struct *next;
} Node;

typedef struct queue_struct {
  Node *head, *tail;
} Queue;

// create a new node, allocating the memory and copying the value...
Node * Node_create(String str) {
  Node *node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if(node == NULL) return NULL;
  node->data = (String)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
  if(node->data == NULL) return NULL;
  strcpy(node->data, str);
  node->next = NULL;
  return node;
}

// delete the node
void Node_delete(Node *node) {
  free(node->data);
  free(node);
}

// create a new Queue and set the head and tail to NULL(empty)
Queue * Queue_create() {
  Queue *queue = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
  if(queue == NULL) return NULL;
  queue->head = queue->tail = NULL;
  return queue;
}

// add a new node to the queue
bool Queue_push(Queue *q, String str) {
  Node* node = Node_create(str);
  if(node == NULL) return false;
  // empty queue
  if(q->head == NULL) {
    q->head = q->tail = node;
  // has only one element
  }else if(q->head == q->tail) {
    q->head->next = q->tail = node;
  // has more than one element
  }else {
    q->tail->next = node;
    q->tail = q->tail->next;
  }
  return true;
}

// print the elements of the queue
void Queue_print(Queue *q) {
  Node *tmpNode = q->head;
  printf("{");
  // loop over the queue
  while(tmpNode != NULL) {
    printf("%s", tmpNode->data);
    // don't print ',' if its the last element
    tmpNode != q->tail && printf(", ");
    tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
  }
  printf("}");
}

// get the size of the queue
int Queue_size(Queue *q) {
  Node *tmpNode = q->head;
  int size = 0;
  while(tmpNode != NULL) {
    tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
    size++;
  }
  return size;
}

// remove the last element in the queue
String Queue_pop(Queue *q) {
  String s = NULL;
  // empty queue
  if(q->head == NULL) return s;
  // has one element
  if(q->head == q->tail) {
    s = q->head->data;
    Node_delete(q->head);
    q->head = q->tail = NULL;
  // has two elements
  }else if(q->head->next == q->tail) {
    s = q->tail->data;
    Node_delete(q->tail);
    q->tail = q->head;
    q->head->next = q->tail;
    q->tail->next = NULL;
  // has more than two
  }else {
    s = q->tail->data;
    Node *tmpNode = q->head, *lastNode;
    // loop over the queue and get the element before the last one
    while(tmpNode != NULL) {
      lastNode = tmpNode;
      tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
      // delete the last element and replace it with the previous element
      if(tmpNode == q->tail) {
        Node_delete(q->tail);
        q->tail = lastNode;
        q->tail->next = NULL;
        return s;
      }
    }
  }
  return s;
}

// remove the first element in the queue
String Queue_shift(Queue *q) {
  String s = NULL;
  // empty queue
  if(q->head == NULL) return NULL;
  // has one element
  if(q->head == q->tail) {
    s = q->head->data;
    Node_delete(q->head);
    q->head = q->tail = NULL;
  // has more than one
  } else {
    // just delete the first element and replace it with the next one
    Node *tmpNode = q->head->next;
    s = q->head->data;
    Node_delete(q->head);
    q->head = tmpNode;
  }
  return s;
}

// remove all the elements in the queue
void Queue_clear(Queue *q) {
  Node *tmpNode = q->head;
  for(int i = 0, n = Queue_size(q);i < n; i++) {
    tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
    // using the Queue_shift instead of Queue_pop because it's faster(low processing cost)
    Queue_shift(q);
  }
}

// remove all the elements in the queue and free the memory of the queue 
void Queue_delete(Queue *q) {
  Queue_clear(q);
  free(q);
}

// check if the queue is empty
bool Queue_isEmpty(Queue *q) {
  return q->head == NULL;
}

int main(void) {
  Queue *a = Queue_create();
  printf("Is empty: %s\n", Queue_isEmpty(a) ? "true" : "false");
  Queue_push(a, "txt1");
  printf("Size: %d\n", Queue_size(a));
  printf("Is empty: %s\n", Queue_isEmpty(a) ? "true" : "false");
  Queue_push(a, "txt2");
  Queue_push(a, "txt3");
  Queue_print(a);
  Queue_shift(a);
  printf("\nSize: %d\n", Queue_size(a));
  Queue_pop(a);
  Queue_push(a, "txt4");
  Queue_push(a, "txt5");
  printf("Size: %d\n", Queue_size(a));
  Queue_print(a);
  Queue_clear(a);
  printf("\nSize: %d\n", Queue_size(a));
  Queue_print(a);
  Queue_push(a, "txt");
  printf("\nSize: %d\n", Queue_size(a));
  Queue_print(a);
  Queue_delete(a);
  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
Is empty: true
Size: 1
Is empty: false
{txt1, txt2, txt3}
Size: 2
Size: 3
{txt2, txt4, txt5}
Size: 0
{}
Size: 1
{txt}
```

---

Ok according to your comment:

> I currently experiment with your version right now i want to ask if i don't want to use Queue *a = Queue_create(); in the main function but instead i want to made Queue *a = NULL; and then allocate space for it in push function how would you do it?

You can do it this way, note that you can still use the other functions the same way with no modifications. and even you still can use Queue_create Directly like `Queue *q = Queue_create();` like in the first part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// make an alias for better readability
typedef char * String;

typedef struct node_struct {
  String data;
  struct node_struct *next;
} Node;

typedef struct queue_struct {
  Node *head, *tail;
} Queue;

// create a new node, allocating the memory and copying the value...
Node * Node_create(String str) {
  Node *node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if(node == NULL) return NULL;
  node->data = (String)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
  if(node->data == NULL) return NULL;
  strcpy(node->data, str);
  node->next = NULL;
  return node;
}

// delete the node
void Node_delete(Node *node) {
  free(node->data);
  free(node);
}

// create a new Queue and set the head and tail to NULL(empty)
Queue * Queue_create() {
  Queue *queue = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
  if(queue == NULL) return NULL;
  queue->head = queue->tail = NULL;
  return queue;
}

// add a new node to the queue
bool Queue_push(Queue **q, String str) {
  // if there is no allocated Queue then we need to allocate one using the Queue_create() we already have
  if(*q == NULL) {
    *q = Queue_create();
    if(*q == NULL) return false;
  }
  Node* node = Node_create(str);
  if(node == NULL) return false;
  // empty queue
  if((*q)->head == NULL) {
    (*q)->head = (*q)->tail = node;
  // has only one element
  }else if((*q)->head == (*q)->tail) {
    (*q)->head->next = (*q)->tail = node;
  // has more than one element
  }else {
    (*q)->tail->next = node;
    (*q)->tail = (*q)->tail->next;
  }
  return true;
}

// print the elements of the queue
void Queue_print(Queue *q) {
  if(q != NULL) {
    Node *tmpNode = q->head;
    printf("{");
    // loop over the queue
    while(tmpNode != NULL) {
      printf("%s", tmpNode->data);
      // don't print ',' if its the last element
      tmpNode != q->tail && printf(", ");
      tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
    }
    printf("}");
  }
}

// get the size of the queue
int Queue_size(Queue *q) {
  if(q == NULL) return 0;
  Node *tmpNode = q->head;
  int size = 0;
  while(tmpNode != NULL) {
    tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
    size++;
  }
  return size;
}

// remove the last element in the queue
String Queue_pop(Queue *q) {
  if(q == NULL) return NULL;
  String s = NULL;
  // empty queue
  if(q->head == NULL) return s;
  // has one element
  if(q->head == q->tail) {
    s = q->head->data;
    Node_delete(q->head);
    q->head = q->tail = NULL;
  // has two elements
  }else if(q->head->next == q->tail) {
    s = q->tail->data;
    Node_delete(q->tail);
    q->tail = q->head;
    q->head->next = q->tail;
    q->tail->next = NULL;
  // has more than two
  }else {
    s = q->tail->data;
    Node *tmpNode = q->head, *lastNode;
    // loop over the queue and get the element before the last one
    while(tmpNode != NULL) {
      lastNode = tmpNode;
      tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
      // delete the last element and replace it with the previous element
      if(tmpNode == q->tail) {
        Node_delete(q->tail);
        q->tail = lastNode;
        q->tail->next = NULL;
        return s;
      }
    }
  }
  return s;
}

// remove the first element in the queue
String Queue_shift(Queue *q) {
  if(q == NULL) return NULL;
  String s = NULL;
  // empty queue
  if(q->head == NULL) return NULL;
  // has one element
  if(q->head == q->tail) {
    s = q->head->data;
    Node_delete(q->head);
    q->head = q->tail = NULL;
  // has more than one
  } else {
    // just delete the first element and replace it with the next one
    Node *tmpNode = q->head->next;
    s = q->head->data;
    Node_delete(q->head);
    q->head = tmpNode;
  }
  return s;
}

// remove all the elements in the queue
void Queue_clear(Queue *q) {
  if(q != NULL) {
    Node *tmpNode = q->head;
    for(int i = 0, n = Queue_size(q);i < n; i++) {
      tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
      // using the Queue_shift instead of Queue_pop because it's faster(low processing cost)
      Queue_shift(q);
    }
  }
}

// remove all the elements in the queue and free the memory of the queue 
void Queue_delete(Queue *q) {
  if(q != NULL) {
    Queue_clear(q);
    free(q);
  }
}

// check if the queue is empty
bool Queue_isEmpty(Queue *q) {
  return q == NULL || q->head == NULL;
}

int main(void) {
  Queue *a = NULL;
  Queue_print(a);
  printf("Is empty: %s\n", Queue_isEmpty(a) ? "true" : "false");
  Queue_push(&a, "txt1");
  printf("Size: %d\n", Queue_size(a));
  printf("Is empty: %s\n", Queue_isEmpty(a) ? "true" : "false");
  Queue_push(&a, "txt2");
  Queue_push(&a, "txt3");
  Queue_print(a);
  Queue_shift(a);
  printf("\nSize: %d\n", Queue_size(a));
  Queue_pop(a);
  Queue_push(&a, "txt4");
  Queue_push(&a, "txt5");
  printf("Size: %d\n", Queue_size(a));
  Queue_print(a);
  Queue_clear(a);
  printf("\nSize: %d\n", Queue_size(a));
  Queue_print(a);
  Queue_push(&a, "txt");
  printf("\nSize: %d\n", Queue_size(a));
  Queue_print(a);
  Queue_delete(a);
  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
Is empty: true
Size: 1
Is empty: false
{txt1, txt2, txt3}
Size: 2
Size: 3
{txt2, txt4, txt5}
Size: 0
{}
Size: 1
{txt}
```

Comment: I currently experiment with your version right now i want to ask if i don't want to use ```Queue *a = Queue_create();``` in the main function but instead i want to made ```Queue *a = NULL;``` and then allocate space for it in push function how would you do it?

Comment: Well I'm sorry for the late response because I was at work, anyway yes it can be done the way you want, you need to make some modifications in the push function to work with a pointer of pointer, and when calling it you need to pass the address of the Queue pointer, but you need to make sure to check for NULL in the other functions as well to prevent errors if the Queue is NULL. I have just edited my post to include the changes you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code. Many would have been caught if you had warnings of your compiler turned on.

In `push`: you want to receive a pointer to your queue. But in main you pas a *double pointer*. In main you also declare your queue as an empty pointer, `Queue *q = NULL;` so there is no queue (not even an empty queue). You can do two things:

- receive the double pointer in `push` and allocate an empty queue that you return in the pointer;
- declare the queue in `main` not as pointer but as an empty queue, `Queue q = {0};` and now call `push(&q, "a");`

In `push` you also make an error in allocating the data. 
With `temp->data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` you allocate only ONE char. 
Then with `temp->data = word;`
you throw it away. You should do:

```
temp->data = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
strcpy(temp->data, word);
```

Comment: So if i want to do double pointer way i need to change my push function like this right 

`void push(Queue **q, char *word)` 

and all q in there need to be (**q) and how do i allocate an empty queue in push tho.

Is it like this `q = (Queue**)malloc(sizeof(Queue*));` ?

Comment: The idea is that the memory you allocate will be "visible" in the caller's pointer variable. So you allocate `*q = malloc(sizeof(Queue));` Within the function you use for example `(*q)->head= temp;`.

Comment: And you should not cast the result of `malloc`. It returns a void pointer, which is compatible with all pointer types.

Comment: i have modify my if condition as follow

```if ((*q)->head == NULL)
    {
        *q = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
        (*q)->head = temp;
    }```
But it don't work because *q is NULL so there are other exception at if condition. I also try to suppurate malloc into it own if condition ```if (*q==NULL)``` and it also not work

Comment: No, of course it won't work because you first have to test `if (*q == NULL)` meaning there is no queue yet. I think you must go back to your books and read about pointers and memory.

Comment: OK, i definitely going back to my lecture note right now because i have this subject midterm exam tomorrow and i still didn't get a grip on the idea about pointers and memory yet.